How can I hide the black background canvas of a TImage?
I would like draw blue lines onto a TImage, which is a child object of a ScrollBox. But when I drawing, it always shows the black background canvas rectangle under the blue lines. I would like see only the lines without the black background rectangle. Can I do a transparent TImage from it?
I tried with this code so far, but it's only partially good:
procedure TForm1.gridButtonMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var bm: TBitmap;
  hlines,vlines: word;
begin
  if showgrid=true then
  begin
     showgrid:=false;
     if gridon=true then
     begin
       FreeAndNil(gridimage);
       gridon:=false;
     end;
  end
  else
  begin
    showgrid:=true;
    if gridon=false then
    begin
      gridimage:=TImage.Create(terrainScrBox);
      gridimage.Parent:=terrainScrBox;
      gridimage.Left:=0;
      gridimage.Top:=0;
      gridimage.width:=terrainCanvas.width; //terrainCanvas is a TImage component.
      gridimage.height:=terrainCanvas.Height;
      griddrawing(gridimage);
    end;
    gridon:=true;
  end;
end;
 
procedure TForm1.griddrawing(Sender: TObject);
var hlines,vlines: word;
begin
     vlines:=tilewidth;
     hlines:=tileheight;
     //with gridimage do // If these lines are commented, the grid is visible without black rectangle,
     //begin // but not at gridimage, but at TForm1, and I can't switch off it.
       canvas.pen.color:=clBlue;
       while vlines<width do
       begin
          canvas.line(vlines,0,vlines,height);
          inc(vlines,tilewidth);
       end;
       while hlines<height do
       begin
          canvas.line(0,hlines,width,hlines);
          inc(hlines,tileheight);
       end;
     //end;
end;


Does this answer your question? How can I restore the default picture of a TImage?

What exactly do you mean with "transparent TImage"? What is the background behind the TImage, that you want to be visible, and what does it look like?

Acknowledging the fact that you are a new member of Stack Overflow and actually haven't visited the [tour], which presents this site in a nutshell, I suggest you visit that page (click the link in previous sentense). Stack Overflow is a "One question - One or more answer(s) site. Specifically, it is not a discussion site. When you post a question, you must prepare it well [mre], with a clear target and all details of what you want help with, so that it can be answered with one answer post. If you realize that you need to ask a new related question, post that question as a new topic.

Also, you are welcome to answer your own questions, if you want to. However, your own answer should be your own and not based on somebody elses answer. Specifically it should not include a new question (as already mentioned in previous comment).

The TImage control is not truly transparent. But I guess that that is not really what you want, but instead that you could define the background color or maybe even a picture that would appear to be behind whatever you want to draw in front of that background.
The default color of the TImage is black, which is why you see the image  (after drawing the lines) as blue lines on a black background.
To change the background color you should, after you have created the gridimage, but just before you call griddrawing, fill the image with the color you want to have as background, e.g.:
  with gridimage do begin
    Brush.Color := clWhite;
    Canvas.FillRect(0, 0, Width, Height);
  end;


I did not fully understand what role the terrainCanvas plays in your setup, but if that should be visible behind the blue lines, then draw that terrainCanvas on the gridImage instead of the FillRect above (before drawing the blue lines).

Hello Tom Brunberg!

Hello Tom Brunberg!
I tried your suggestion, but the result is the similar (with colors clWhite and clNone), just now with white background.
I would like get the effect when I commented that lines in procedure griddrawing, and it this case I finally get only the blue grid lines, but on TForm1.

@Progizo So, is it the picture in terrainCanvas that you want to see in the gridimage behind the blue lines? Please confirm. If not, then you have to edit your question and be very clear about what you want.

Hello Tom Brunberg!
TerrainCanvas is a TImage within the ScrollBox (which is the parent of terrainCanvas) and I would like draw a grid and numbers onto it. To this, I use an other TImage component (gridimage), but when I use drawing commands (e.g. canvas.line()) on it, it always shows its colored canvas.
So, I would like a TImage component, behind which you can see without being covered by the canvas and showing only the grid drawn on it.

Almost good!
As you suggested above ("draw that terrainCanvas on the gridImage instead of the FillRect above (before drawing the blue lines)") I modified my code:
if gridon=false then
begin
      gridimage:=TImage.Create(terrainScrBox);
      gridimage.Parent:=terrainScrBox;
      gridimage.Left:=0;
      gridimage.Top:=0;
      gridimage.width:=terrainCanvas.width;
      gridimage.height:=terrainCanvas.Height;
      gridimage.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(terrainCanvas.width,terrainCanvas.height);
      gridimage.picture.bitmap.Assign(terrainCanvas.picture.bitmap);
      gridimage.OnPaint:=@griddrawing;
      gridimage.invalidate;
end;

So, now it only shows the blue grid and the terrainCanvas under it. This is what I wanted.
But one more small mistake: when the grid is on and visible, I cannot modify the content of terrainCanvas. What is the reason of this? I would like add details to the terrainCanvas when the grid is visible, too - if possible.
